# La bellezza del somaro

Tags: regional, phrase-origin

L'espressione *la bellezza del somaro* o *la bellezza dell'asino* è piuttosto conosciuta, ad esempio è anche usata da Italo  Calvino:

> la bellezza dell'asino di cui anche i libri s'adornano, che dura
> finché la copertina non comincia a ingiallire, un velo di smog a
> depositarsi sul taglio [...].    *(Se una notte d’inverno un viaggiatore)*.

Ha il significatio di una bellezza dovuta esclusivamente alla giovane età, quindi scontata, e passeggera.

Io la uso anche, e l'ho sentita usare, in modo più esteso come sinonimo di 'qualità scontata, senza merito.' Non so se sia un uso canonico, ma non m'importa, perché è una espressione che mi piace usare.

Mi viene  in mente ultimamente, quando vengo qui su Italian SE, dove mi dico che ho la bellezza del somaro, cioè la competenza senza merito di chi è nato e vissuto in Italia.

Quella che è incerta è l'origine di questa espressione.

Una possibilità è che tragga origine dal fatto che gli asini da piccoli sono particolarmente carini.

La versione più diffusa è che venga dal modo di dire francese *la beauté de l’âge* (bellezza dell’età), che poi nel parlato si sarebbe corrotto in *la beauté de l'âne* (bellezza dell'asino).

Vocabolario Treccani e Dizionario del Corriere della Sera però, riportando entrambe le origini, dubitano della derivazione francese:

https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bellezza/

https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/B/bellezza.shtml

Anche a me sembra strano che *âge* si sia corrotto in *âne*, perché il passaggio da una *g* a una *n* mi sembra insolito.

Ci sono lettere che si modificano le une nelle altre come ad esempio le labiali, *b* diventa facilmente *v* e viceversa, o lettere  come *a-* (nel senso dell' *alpha* privativo) che può essere equivalente al suffisso *in-* (a-morale/immorale ad esempio)<sup>1</sup>, ma la trasformazione di *g* in *n* mi suona strano.

D'altra parte, non avendo conosciuto asini da piccoli, non so nemmeno giudicare l'attendibilità dell'altra origine, anche questa mi suona un po' bizzarra.

Che ci siano degli usi regionali o episodi particolari all'origine? Quacuno sa qualcosa della possibile etimologia?

In particolare, ad esempio, se si potesse stabilire che c'è un uso tradizionale di questa espressione in regioni che non hanno visto la dominazione e l'influenza francese, si potrebbe già ipotizzare che l'ascendenza francese è discutibile.
Io sono di Napoli, lì parole di derivazione francese ce ne sono tante, ma mai sentito *la bellezza del somaro* come detto tradizionale napoletano.

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sup>Dai ricordi del ginnasio, la professoressa ci diceva che entrambi i suffissi vengono  dalla *enne*  indoeuropea.</sup>

Comment: A me sembra di averla sentita usare (ma posso sbagliare) soltanto nel senso che accenni di una bellezza che sfuma rapidamente, come quella di una persona giovane, “fresca”, con una bella pelle etc., ma che non è veramente _bella_, e crescendo d'età non ha nulla di mirabile. Questo uso sarebbe compatibile con l'esempio tratto da Calvino. Sull'origine non so nulla: sono curioso.

Comment: Ma infatti, l'uso conosciuto è quello, di una bellezza ovvia, senza grandi qualità, sono io che l'ho adottata in senso più esteso, metaforico, adattandola ad altre occasioni, per dire una abilità scontata, senza merito, perché mi piace e mi diverte. L'origine è misteriosa, mai capita.